# Check if string in list of strings equals one value in list in dictionary, then assign key value to variable

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

**Set-up**

I am working on a scraping project with Scrapy.

I have a list of strings,

```
l = ['john', 'jim', 'jacob', … ,'jonas']
```

and a dictionary containing lists,

```
d = {
 'names1': ['abel', 'jacob', 'poppy'],
 'names2': ['john', 'tom', 'donald']
}
```

---

**Problem**

I'd like to check for each name in `l` wether it is in contained in one of the lists in `d`. If so, I want the key of that list in `d` to be assigned to a new variable. E.g. `jacob` would get `newvar = names1`.

For now I have,

```
found = False
for key,value in d.items():
     for name in l:
          if name == value:
              newvar = key
              found = True
              break
     else:
         newvar = 'unknown'
     if found:
         break
```

However, this results in `newvar = 'unknown'` for every `name` in `l`.

I think I'm not breaking out of the outer `for` loop correctly. Other than that, is there perhaps a more elegant way to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do this? I mean that new variable you want to create every time.

Comment: Yes, it's part of a Scrapy spider: I assign `newvar` to a dictionary later on.

Comment: Is it a matter of changing `if name == value` to `if name in value`? Or am I reading this wrong? 'Cause it seems to me like `value` there would be a list, and not a single name.

Comment: Why not immediately assigning it to a dictionary?

Comment: @Marcy No, I tried that. Doesn't change.

Comment: @Elmex80s Due to the scraping proces I obtain numerous variables and I insert them all at once in the dictionary per item scraped.

Comment: Why adding them all at once? There is nothing wrong updating a dict

Comment: possible dupe/overlap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is you want to see if any string in l exists in a value in d. Your code now is assuming that the value is a string, not a list, and you are thus trying to make a comparison, which will always be false, therefore assigning "unkown" to every value. Try this code below:

```
l = ['john', 'jim', 'jacob', 'jonas']
d = {'names1': ['abel', 'jacob', 'poppy'], 'names2': ['john', 'tom','donald']}
found = False
for a, b in d.items():
   for i in l:
       if i in b:
           d[a] = "unkown"
           flag = True
           break

   if flag:
   break

print d
```

This will give you:

```
{'names2': 'unkown', 'names1': ['abel', 'jacob', 'poppy']}
```

Since you break out of the loop, only one key has an "unknown" value, but if you wanted to replace every value that contains a string in l with unkown, this will work as well:

```
final_dict = {a:"unkown" if i not in b else b for i in l for a, b in d.items()}

print final_dict
```